# No sound, very small icon. HP Spectre x360

Tags: 14.04, sound, hp

I've just bought a new laptop hp spectre x360, there are to irritating issues:

1- Sound doesn't work, I have tried what is been said on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) page with no success.

**Output from terminal**

```
pi@HP-laptop:~$ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
snd_hda_intel          30469  2 
snd_hda_controller     30228  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139682  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    79468  13 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0 
pi@HP-laptop:~$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
pi@HP-laptop:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 802d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63
    Memory at b2210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
```

2-Icons are very small, there was a partial solution by enlarging the fonts but it, still some icons are small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone over on HP's support forums [found a solution](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-PC-Sound-and-Audio/HP-spectre-x360-on-linux/m-p/5122160#M66839) for the lack of sound. You should make sure you back up your computer first, as it does involve modifying GRUB's configuration. The steps are:

> Edit grub config by doing:
>
> '`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`'
>
> Edit the line:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash'"`
>
> To:
>
> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"`
>
> Then run:
>
> '`sudo update-grub`'
>
> Reboot TWO times.

You may need to alter volume or mute settings afterwards.

Comment: Might need to add that there's a BIOS  dependency here. The above fix will NOT work if you have an older BIOS.

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked, and I tried tons of things!

Comment: Any explanation why this works?

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga At a guess, it's telling GRUB to set some firmware config options into a state that the Linux kernel circa 2015 could recognize. But I'm not familiar enough with GRUB, ACPI, or the Linux kernel's inner workings to say with any certainty.

Comment: Thanks for the response @8bittree. I'm struggling with getting my speakers to work on HP X360, but through the headphones, I can get sound fine. Maybe I need to post as a question.

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga Keep in mind that this question and my answer are from when the original, Broadwell-based HP Spectre x360 was the only Spectre x360 and when Ubuntu 14.04 was current. Both the hardware and the software have gone through many changes since then, so if you're using something more recent, a new question is probably appropriate. You can always link back here as a reference for something you've tried that didn't work.