# No sound in Ubuntu on HP Spectre x360

Tags: sound, hp

I really like my new HP Spectre x360 laptop and it performs fine running Windows 10 Pro (except for the strange overheating issue, interestingly not present in Ubuntu), except in Ubuntu 15.04, the speakers and headphone jack don't work and no internal soundcard is detected in the sound settings. I read somewhere that HP made the internal soundcard run in I2S mode instead of HDA mode, and that Ubuntu doesn't support I2S soundcards. Is this true? Is there some way I can get the audio to work in Ubuntu on my laptop? I really do like using Ubuntu, but it's awfully disappointing that the speakers and headphone jack don't work. The specific model is the HP 4102dx with a Broadwell processor.

Comment: Did you try as in this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/633568/no-sound-very-small-icon-hp-spectre-x360?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the provided link is fantastic, this totally works!
It also seems to solve the problem of suspend not working on the HP Spectre x360 in Ubuntu 15.10 completely!

```
Edit grub config by doing:

'sudo emacs -nw /etc/default/grub'

Edit the line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash'"

To:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"

Then run:

'sudo update-grub'

Reboot TWO times.
```

Comment: this one is needed with x360 broadwell based. Is the same problem present and solution needed for x360 skylake based ?

Comment: On my x360 (model 4105-no) with i5-6200U (that's skylake I guess?), I have seen no sound issues

Comment: As of kernel 4.8.x, the broadwell based rt286 soundcard is supported.